# Where could be inline-css in Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

I am working on this webpage:http://hypoinvest.sk/ which runs on Wordpress with [this theme](https://shapebootstrap.net/item/1524965-flat-theme-free-responsive-multipurpose-site-template) If you check source code you can see a lot of inline-css and I want to know in which files are actually defined. Only thing what I know about it they are called by function wp_head() in header.php. I have local copy of all files on this web and I can't find any mention about some of that css rules through unix grep. Anyone suspect where these css rules could be located?

check site and let me know.

Comment: they're most probably loaded with the [`wp_add_inline_style()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_add_inline_style) function, called in your theme's functions.php file, or a file included/required by that one

Comment: Are you talking about the inline CSS from `line 80` to `line 463`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run a search in the source code for

```
style-inline
```

As this appears to be the 'handle' designated as the first variable in the function **wp_add_inline_style**. The "-css" is added automatically. You'll see this on line 79 of the page source.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_add_inline_style

Answer (score 1):

You want to check your page back-end site where you put content ,
I think are you using any compose or editor to create page on edit page.

check it edit option it has some inline css.

Comment: Yes I found it thank to this. Finally it was in wp-admin -> appearances -> theme options -> custom css